# In Javascript how to detect Browser or Tab Close event?

Tags: javascript

In my Application i want to detect Browser or Tab close event and then for this event would like to submit form for logout function and clear user session.

I have tried window.onbeforeunload event but it is fire for all even i click link or refresh page.

Any one can please help me.

Comment: you can checkout my answer for this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73904773/14870617

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific API to achieve what you want.

What you **can** do is the following:

1. Issue access/session tokens with (relatively) short lifespans (like 1 minute)
2. Have your frontend "continuously" refresh the tokens to keep the application signed in

In this way after a (relatively) small delay if the frontend is not running you end up with an expired session/access token and the user is effectively logged out.

Cons of this approach: if the user has a small window of connectivity problems their session will expire. If your system is a mobile application this might make your App very frustrating to use in various circumstances. Might not be a big problem if your use case is access from workstations.

Comment: No my frontend didnot "continuously" refresh the tokens

Comment: @namratamahajan Yeah... that's what I was saying. You can modify your code so that it refreshes the authentication tokens frequently. In this way you can reduce the time between when a tab is closed and when the session times out. Obviously the shorter the session time the higher the chances of expiring by accident.