# Call Logout API on Browser Window Close

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

Identity Server is generating HTTPOnly Cookies. Not able to access these using client-side JavaScript. When the user closes the browser without logging out, we are having issues with these cookies. We need to delete them when the browser is closed. But on the beforeunload event, when Logout is called it is not calling the controller method. Any ideas on how to handle this.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "/LoginIdentity/Logout",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }, 500);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139970/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event-using-signalr

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  if (fetch) {
    fetch('/LoginIdentity/Logout', {
      method: "GET",
      keepalive: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(function (response) {
                
    }).then(function (response) {

    });
    return false;
  } else {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/LoginIdentity/Logout",
        success: function (data) {
                       
        },
        error: function (response) {

        }
      });
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ran into another Issue. Unable to distinguish between Mouse Click on Refresh and Close.

Answer (score 0):

**Note : This is my personal code for one my application where I have done similar type of logic of logout user**

You can use Browser Native Broadcast api for check is there multiple table open or not of current application and is there broswer is closed or tabs are closed or not.

Fo that you need to add this code in your HTML page. This will help you to set and get your app browser count and based on that you can forcefully call logout api.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // logic for get or set item in localstorage during load
            new BroadcastChannel('yourapp').postMessage('ASPMYAPP');
            if (!localStorage.getItem('myappstabs')) {
                localStorage.setItem('myappstabs', 1);
            }

            // logic for increase the tab counter by browser broadcast api in localstorage during running application on multiple tabs
            new BroadcastChannel('yourapp').addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                let countTabs = localStorage.getItem('myappstabs');
                localStorage.setItem('myappstabs', parseInt(countTabs) + 1);
            })

            //Final code for logout user if user directly close the last tab of application or close the broswer
            $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
                let avaiCount = localStorage.getItem('myappstabs');
                if (localStorage.getItem('myappstabs') && localStorage.getItem('myappstabs') == 1) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/LoginIdentity/Logout",
                        type: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            // success callback
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('logout successfully');
                    localStorage.removeItem('myappstabs');
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem('myappstabs', parseInt(avaiCount) - 1);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```